# Can't render variables in ion-card inside an ng-repeat - Ionic 4 Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I made a project using Ionic 4.5.0 within Angular, it worked properly until I tried to update Ionic to 4.11.9.

The problem is that the variables present inside the ion-cards inside an ng-repeat have stopped being rendered, giving the console this error:

`Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined`

The problem is only about ion-cards, the other Ionic components work properly, and it seems to be related to the use of ui-router.

**I made an example on Codepen https://codepen.io/andreavalzasina/pen/BaNLNqR**

Has there been a particular change on this specific component in the latest ionic releases? 
Is there any way to solve this problem, without having to stay at version 4.5.0 or having to change all the ion-cards of the project with other custom components?

Comment: Did you update the version of an other dependency (like AngularJS) or did you just change the verison of Ionic?

Comment: I only updated Ionic

Comment: It's seems to be working with the version 5.0.1 of Ionic. Could it be a solution for you ?

Comment: Yes it seems to be the only solution, thanks